# C++: Entering ComplexNumber (imaginary and real part) operator again ComplexNumber, and so on

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, istream

i get into trouble, i've to write program with two classes ComplexNumber and Equation, in Equation class i need to overload operator `>>`. Now they want to overload it like this, first we enter REAL then IMAGINARY then operator and again ComplexNumber with these atributes, and to stop entering when we input `=` char, so i get confused here and i need your help, how can i do that?

Here is my Equation class

```
class Equation{
private:
    ComplexNumber *cns;
    char *operatori;
    int len=0;
public:
    Equation(ComplexNumber *cns=0,char *operatori=0)
    {
        this->len=len;
        this->cns = new ComplexNumber[len];
        for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            this->cns[i]=cns[i];
        }

        this->operatori = new char [strlen(operatori)+1];
        strcpy(this->operatori,operatori);
    }

    Equation (const Equation &e)
    {
        this->len=e.len;
        this->cns = new ComplexNumber[e.len];
        for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            this->cns[i]=e.cns[i];
        }

        this->operatori = new char [strlen(e.operatori)+1];
        strcpy(this->operatori,e.operatori);
    }

    Equation &operator =( Equation &e)
    {
        if (this != &e)
        {

        delete [] cns;
        delete [] operatori;

        this->len=e.len;
        this->cns = new ComplexNumber[e.len];
        for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            this->cns[i]=e.cns[i];
        }

        this->operatori = new char [strlen(e.operatori)+1];
        strcpy(this->operatori,e.operatori);

        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: It will help if you show the code you have written so far. It's impossible to say how to overload `operator>>` for an `Equation` class without seeing the `Equation` class you have written.

Comment: @john i have edited my ask with uploaded code of my class Equation.